# Error Using New JavaScript Array Methods in Quokka.js within Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, quokka.js

I am encountering an issue while experimenting with the latest JavaScript array methods in Quokka.js within Visual Studio Code. I'm trying to use the following new array methods: `toSorted()`, `toReserved()`, `with()`, and `toSpliced()`.

However, I'm consistently getting an error, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. The error message is as follows:

```
numbers.toSorted is not a function
```

[image]

Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```js
let numbers = [5, 4, 1, 2, 3];
let result = numbers.toSorted();

console.log(numbers);
console.log(result);
```

I would appreciate any guidance on how to address this error and successfully use these new array methods in Quokka.js.